# How to convert the elements of a cell array from double to char?

Tags: matlab, char, double, cell-array

So ,

i have a cell array(1x5 cell) like this:

```
{[1111] [1111] [1010] [1000] [1011]}
```

the elements inside the cell array are type of double , but i want them to be type of char like this :

```
{'1111' '1111' '1010' '1000' '1011'}
```

i tried to convert them with num2str but i get the error **Undefined function 'abs' for input arguments of type 'cell'.** , basically meaning that i cannot use the function num2str for cell arrays

Anyone has an idea how to convert double to char in cell arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You can [loop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) over all the cells.

```
input = {1111, 1111, 1010, 1000, 1011};
output = cellfun(@num2str, input, 'un', 0);
```

```
>> output
output =
  1×5 cell array
    {'1111'}    {'1111'}    {'1010'}    {'1000'}    {'1011'}
```

---

Alternatively there is this [string](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) class available since R2016b which may be relevant to use for your case:

```
outstr = string(input);
```

```
>> outstr
outstr = 
  1×5 string array
    "1111"    "1111"    "1010"    "1000"    "1011"
```

However if you strictly want a cell array with characters in each cell, you can further use [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html):

```
output = cellstr(outstr);
```

Comment: i tried that but i got an output like this: {'1  1  1  1' .......} .For some reason matlab added some spaces between every bit

Comment: @Γιάννης What did you run? Did you try running the first code-block (which includes your input and cellfun)

Comment: Yes i tried the first code block :output=[cellfun(@num2str,input(1:end),'un',0)] where input is my initial cell array with elements of type double

Comment: Not that it will make any difference but the above line is not the copy-paste of what I wrote: Also did you run `input = {1111, 1111, 1010, 1000, 1011};` before that line?  Please run the first block *completely as it is written in the answer*

Comment: Yeah i tried it with your input and perfectly worked .In my case i have a 1x5 cell array and  every element of the cell array is 1x4 double .Maybe this helps?

Comment: I have used the input that you have given in the question. It is not 1x4. It is 1x1.

Comment: I am so sorry my mistake.